# Project not getting generated when using Azure Kubernetes Service ifrom Azure DevOps demo genarator

Tags: azure, devops, azure-aks

Error while creating build definition: The pipeline is not valid. A task is missing. The pipeline references a task called 'a8515ec8-7254-4ffd-912c-86772e2b5962'. This usually indicates the task isn't installed, and you may be able to install it from the Marketplace: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com. (Task version , job 'Phase_1', step ''.) A task is missing. The pipeline references a task called 'a8515ec8-7254-4ffd-912c-86772e2b5962'. This usually indicates the task isn't installed, and you may be able to install it from the Marketplace: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com. (Task version , job 'Phase_1', step ''.)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution to the problem, after making some research. These are the steps i followed:

1. Delete the existing project from azure devops
2. Go to marketplace and install these 2 extensions (they are both available and free in the store):

- Kubernetes extension
- Replace tokens

3. Create the project again, and that's all.